# Aiogram не видит админку

Tags: python, django, aiogram

Есть готовый проект бота. Мне поставили задачу прикрутить к нему админку Django и собирать данные, которые вносит пользователь в бота. Создал проект, создал простую модель для тестов. Админка работает.

Бот запускается через python main.py. Сделал, чтобы сообщение пользователя записывалось в БД джанго, но при попытке запуска python main.py вылазит ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adminpanel'

Я так понимаю, как раз не находится модуль админки. Как мне прописать этот модуль и самое главное где?

Comment: если я правильно понимаю вашу задачу, Вам необходимо сделать джанго проект отдельным сервисом и с помощью aiohttp делать GET запрос если вам нужно получить информацию или POST запрос если необходимо вносить информацию в модель ну и модель зарегистрировать в админке.